# Start IIS "process cannot access the file" Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Tags: iis, iis-10

When I try to start the IIS I got: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Even after reboot it wasn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this took my quite a while I post this answer hoping this wil losave some one time.

**The short described solution**

I had to close skype before starting the iis

**The details**

There are many reasons for this error. mostlikely when port 80 is blocked by another software.

Now Skype uses port 80 and if it is started before iis the port of my default website (80) is blocked.

You can check which application is blocking your port by using netstat

```
NETSTAT -ano
```

or any software which shows you who is occupying which port.

btw. in the case of skype it is using another poirt when 80 is used so you won't have any further problem with this

Answer (score 1):

put the iis service into automatic? this would ensure that iis would use available resources before anyone would attempt to.

Comment: Yes I had this but for some reasons since this morning it was slower then skype. Thats also the reason why i was so confused because it worked for an year. Also I installed some updates this morning. not sure if there is a relation

Comment: can you look for the service of skype then put it on "Automatic (delayed start)" , this would make the skype to start after all services that were set to "Automatic" were finished.

Comment: The skype process it self isn't a windows service it is just an automated start applicacation. I don't need it in autostart so there is no problem for me. the problem was that initially i didn't know it was skype :-)

Comment: understood, as per documentation, someone is using the port 80 or 443. you dont have any other web server installed arent you? if so, here's the link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/kb/973094 . this is as far as i can go as i cannot simulate your problem on my pc. tip is look for any suspecious running services.

Comment: as said it was skype using port 80 (see my answer below) after closing it works

Comment: ON SKYPE: Tools -> Connection Options -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as additional incoming connection". pls try and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

ON SKYPE: Tools -> Connection Options -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as additional incoming connection". pls try and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which process use port 80 or 433, use

```
netstat -aon | more
```

command in command promt. You can see Pid (process id).
Stop process in Task Manager (find it by id)
Than restart IIS.
Check this out: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/

Comment: The link that you provided no longer exists. You should edit your question to include how to tell what process is listening on a tcpip port.